# CoreData Light migration Xcode 10 with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to modify my CoreData attributes, and after I did that, I tried to do the light migration, but the log still showing me the error "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"

What I did:

- created a new model version, linked to the pervious one
- Added the new attribute into the new model version
- set the new model as current model
- update AppDelegate.m code

I attached a screenshot for myAppDelegate.m file

[image]

am I missing something  here?

Comment: What about the model identifiers? The original model needs to have one and the new one needs to have something different.

Comment: model identifier ? how can I change that ?

Comment: @trapper I did that, I put the original version to 1, and the new one to 2, but still not working.